# "The type or namespace name `Packages' could not be found" when consuming OData feed

Tags: c#, xamarin, odata

I want to test the following simple example but getting the highlighted error. I have the following namespace `using Simple.OData.Client`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check my updated question, I added already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've copied code from either [here](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Getting-started-with-Simple.OData.Client) or [here](https://components.xamarin.com/view/simple.odata.client), where it is stated that both are examples, not working code.

In order to deserialize a feed into a class, that class must exist. The OData client library you use has no connection whatsoever to NuGet, it just uses its feed as an example.

At the latter link it is also mentioned:

> Simple.OData.Client doesn't generate proxy classes but you should be able to easily add classes for entities you plan to use by navigating to the OData feed and inspecting its metadata. Use URL $metadata to obtain metadata description. If you have Visual Studio you can create a proxy by creating a project and adding service reference to it. Then you can use the generated classes.

From the URL http://www.nuget.org/api/v1/$metadata you should be able to create a Service Reference (of which you will not use the proxy) that will generate the `V1FeedPackage` type, which you can then use:

```
var packages = await client
    .For<V1FeedPackage>()
    .Filter(x => x.Title == "Simple.OData.Client")
    .FindEntriesAsync();

foreach (var package in packages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(package.Title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot CodeCaster, do you have any idea of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502359/accessing-odata-after-setting-up-the-cookie

Comment: @casillas that's exactly what I pointed out in my answer and what is taught in the pages I linked to. In order to consume an API, you either use `dynamic` or you generate classes from the service's metadata, then call `.FindEntriesAsync()`.